# Newer version of app doesnot install

Tags: android

I download the higher version of app from server .It downloads correctly but as soon as i try to replace it with current version. It says application not installed.
there is a service running behind app that autostarts the app on boot up.I am really hooked up..Please help!!!

P.S. There is no problem in apk .I have seperately tried to install it and its working fine.

Answer (score 2):

This can happen because the signature of the new app does not match with the old one.
Try uninstalling the older version first. That should fix the problem.

Comment: exactly right. if that doesnt work the apk might be incompatible with your device. if it is a system app though you might need root access to delete/uninstall the old version as well as possibly for installing the newer version!